# Why can not I see my codes result lively in VSCODE? Live server has problem I think

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed extensions offline through VSIX file format, because I could not download online due to an unexpected error. My problem is when I would type codes, the result would not appear in browser as live, and if I want see my result I must either close and reopen my browser or switch live server off then on

I have done only either close and reopen my browser or switch live server off then on

Comment: why don't you create an issue at the Liver Server extension repo

Comment: How? What do you mean?